# Stored procedure from Codeigniter

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

How to prevent multiple execution of stored procedure for single request?

```
$from_statecode = 'TN'; 
$this->db->query("Declare @CurrentInvoiceNo int 
                             Execute spSetInvoiceNoStatewise '$from_statecode', @CurrentInvoiceNo output
                             select @CurrentInvoiceNo");
```

Stored procedure : spSetInvoiceNoStatewise, is following:-

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[spSetInvoiceNoStatewise]
@StateCode nvarchar(20),
@InvoiceNo int = 0 output
AS
Begin
select @InvoiceNo=invoice_no from statewise_invoice_no where invoice_state_code=@StateCode

if(@InvoiceNo is not NULL) 
        UPDATE statewise_invoice_no set invoice_no = @InvoiceNo + 1 where invoice_state_code = @StateCode

if(@InvoiceNo is NULL) 
        insert into statewise_invoice_no (invoice_state_code,invoice_no) values (@StateCode, 1);

select @InvoiceNo=invoice_no from statewise_invoice_no where invoice_state_code=@StateCode

End
```

Is there anything wrong with the stored procedure?
Or what can be done to prevent the multiple execution for single request?

I have gone through articles which suggests to  "**Lock a resource or transactions**"

Comment: I don't think CI has functionality to lock. Check the docs.

Comment: Any other method to prevent such issue?